# Is my circuit analysis correct in this problem?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, resistance

This is the problem:
[image]

My solution:

I'm new the delta-to-y and y-to-delta transformation, it is obvious we need to use them. I got the same answer but I'm a bit skeptical about my solution.

[image]

Is my solution and analysis correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is 0.8 Ohm but step 3 is wrong, the joint of two 1.9 Ohm resistor at both side should be connected to the joint of two 1 Ohm resistor at the middle. Solving the problem again would be a good idea.

I would like to suggest you two good practice.

1. \$\frac{1}{3}={0.333333…}\$ in this case if you consider the result 0.3 then it will result in poor accuracy in the final result. Take at least 2 or 3 digits after decimal point like 0.33 or 0.333.
2. When applying delta-y and y-delta conversion if you find all of the three resistor with same value then use \$R_y=\frac{R_d}{3}\$ and \$R_d = 3R_y\$.